# How to encrypt communication between a desktop app and a REST-based web service?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, desktop-application

I have built a Java desktop application that communicates with RESTful APIs deployed in a Spring Boot webapp. Spring Boot is configured to use embedded Tomcat. I know I need to encrypt the data between these 2 but I don't know much about using certificates.

I'm assuming I need to configure Tomcat with SSL. There is some documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl

I think I need to create my own certificate (is this called a self-signed certificate?) and add the private key to the key store accessed by Tomcat and the public key to the key store distributed in the desktop app. Is that correct so far?

I've heard mention of using commercial certificates. What are these and should I be using them in favour of my own?

Right now the webapp doesn't accept user logins. It just has some public pages with no sensitive data and provides APIs that do communicate sensitive data. If I add pages that require user login is it correct that my self-signed certificate will not work with browsers? Is that where commercial certificates come into play?

Sorry for all the questions in one posting. I'm starting with very limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin, self signed certificates are not certified by Certificate authorities like Verisign. As such, the browser will throw a warning to a user, when they try to access the website.

Commercial certificates, are same as self signed except that instead of you signing, Versign will sign them. This gives validity for the certificate.

Typically for internal testing, self signed is OK, but when you are exposing your app to outside users, you would need a commercial certificate.